# Use a MOSFET to switch on/off power supply for a low power microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, circuit-analysis, low-power, analog-switch

I am trying to develop a circuit that can switch on and off the power supply for a microcontroller. I have around 0.2 - 0.7 V which I can generate to control the electronic switch.
My idea was to use a MOSFET because the circuit needs to be low power can only have leakage currents up to 0.1 uA

something like this:
[image]

(did I choose the resistance for the microcontroller - load too low?)

Although I researched about MOSFETs I somehow still don't get it.
so here are my specifications in summary:

- Micrcontroller with 3 V battery supply
- Electronic switch to turn off/on power supply with an available controlling voltage of around
  0.2 - 0.7 V
- Leakage current if possible not higher than 0.1 uA

The controlling voltage comes from a small photodiode.
I need to figure out if this is possible with these specifications or if I need an opamp or something?

I looked at this MOSFET: https://www.mouser.ch/datasheet/2/115/DIOD_S_A0004567300_1-2542480.pdf, as it has a low Vgs threshold voltage. But I haven't figured out yet if it fits or not.

thankful for every help:)

Answer (score 2):

> *something like this*

The gate-source threshold voltage is usually not a reliable voltage to properly switch on a load but, in any case, that gate-source voltage is the voltage that the gate needs to be relative to the source hence, if you require 3 volts on the source (to power your load) then the gate voltage needs to be at least 1.2 volts higher (4.2 volts) and this appears to be beyond what your photodiode can provide.

My advice is to use a P channel MOSFET with drain connected to your load and source connected to your incoming 3 volt supply. You might then be able to use a low power comparator to activate your P channel MOSFET. Something like (but not the same as) this: -

[image]

It uses a low power comparator (suggestion) and a P channel MOSFET (suggestion) to activate a load once Vbatt is sufficiently high. Taken from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/321300/how-can-i-modify-this-circuit-to-if-once-the-battery-turned-off-never-turn-on-a/321305#321305) and [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/388843/cheap-and-simple-way-so-switch-on-and-off-based-on-voltage-with-hysteresis/388850#388850).

[Here's](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/516471/voltage-comparator-how-to-get-a-stable-voltage-reference-from-a-battery/516481#516481) another Q and A that covers using a very low power comparator to do what I believe you need (and [another](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/516100/trigger-relay-at-different-voltages-with-voltage-comparator/516102#516102)): -

[image]

Comment: [Please take the tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand the motivation behind people giving free help.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the photodiode can supply enough charge to turn on the MOSFET, in theory it would be possible to make this work. However, there are a couple issues.

You have the microcontroller connected between the source of the mosfet and ground, which means that you might need much more than the MOSFETs threhsold voltage to turn it on. Generally, you would want to connect an N-channel MOSFET on the low side of the microcontroller, so that its source pin is grounded, making it easier to control the gate with a ground-referenced voltage.

A possibly simpler way of doing what it sounds like you're trying to do is to use a sleep-mode of your microcontroller, with an interrupt to wake it up once the photodiode detects light. Depending on your requirements and part choice, this can be done with a simple pin-interrupt, using an analog comparator peripheral, or by periodically waking the microcontroller to sample the photodiode voltage with an ADC.

Answer (score 0):

Thank guys. So I did a new simulation, based on your answers:
v_photodiode is my photodiode which is giving pulses of 0.7V for around 3 seconds.
[image]

It looks already better now :)
The problem now is that v_load is not switching off. I guess this has to do with the connection for the P-MOSFET and/or the resistors. I used the Universal Opamp in LT spice for this simulation. Maybe I need to choose another MOSFET. But this is primarily also for helping my understanding of MOSFETs.

I will also try to simulate a circuit without a MOSFET, like the other suggestion.